# :hover works only on lower part of rotateX transformed div

Tags: css, hover, css-transforms

I have div with CSS rotateX transform applied to it:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(500px)  rotateX(60deg) rotateY(60deg) ;
```

and a bunch of smaller div's floated in it, with :hover rule applied to them.
The problem is that only half of inner divs react to :hover event.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNxgn/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you remove in css `height: 200px` all block will react hover event